# Foreground Service cannot be stopped on any other instance in the app - android kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

Once I launch the application , the background service can be started and stopped very well on click of button.

But, this only works fine until I am in the same instance of the app.

When I start the service and kills the application without stopping the service, and if I reopen the application afterwards, I am unable to stop the service on the button click from this instance.

This is my `locationService` class

```
class LocationServiceforeground:Service() {
private val CHANNEL_ID = "foregroundService"

companion object{
    fun startService(context: Context,message:String){
        val startIntent = Intent(context,LocationServiceforeground::class.java)
        startIntent.putExtra("inputextra",message)
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context,startIntent)
    }
    fun stopService(context: Context){
        val stopIntent = Intent(context,LocationServiceforeground::class.java)
        context.stopService(stopIntent)
    }
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    val input = intent?.getStringExtra("inputExtra")
    createNotificationChannel()
    val notificationIntent = Intent(this,UserActivity::class.java)

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("foreground working")
        .setContentText(input)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.locationtrack)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()
    startForeground(1,notification)
    return START_NOT_STICKY
}
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
}
private fun createNotificationChannel(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"foreground service 1",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        manager!!.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
    }
}

override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    this.stopSelf()
}
```

This is my `UserActivity`:

```
class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var location: ImageView
lateinit var locationGif: ImageView
lateinit var beingTrack: TextView
lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
var isLocationSharing = false
lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
lateinit var sharePreference:SharedPreferences
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user)
    sharePreference = getSharedPreferences("sharePref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val username = sharePreference.getString("username", "")
    val logoutBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.logoutUser)
    val statechange = findViewById<Button>(R.id.stateChange)
    val statechange1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.stateChange1)
    val switchBtn = findViewById<SwitchCompat>(R.id.switchBtn)
    locationGif = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.locationGif)
    Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.locatiogif).into(locationGif)
    beingTrack = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.beingTrack)
    location = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.location)


    if (sharePreference.getString("isChecked", "") == "true") {
        switchBtn.isChecked = true
        shareLocation()
    } else {
        switchBtn.isChecked = false
        isLocationSharing = false
        LocationServiceforeground.stopService(this)
        stopSharing()
    }

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
        interval = 200
        fastestInterval = 100
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    }

    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            locationResult ?: return
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

            if (isLocationSharing) {
                for (location in locationResult.locations) {
                    val currentLat = location.latitude
                    val currentLong = location.longitude
                    database.child("$username").child("latitude").setValue(currentLat)
                    database.child("$username").child("longtitude").setValue(currentLong)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    logoutBtn.setOnClickListener {
        stopSharing()
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
        val editor = sharePreference.edit()
        editor.putBoolean("isActive", false)
        editor.putString("username", "")
        editor.apply()
    }
    switchBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val editor = sharePreference.edit()
        if (switchBtn.isChecked) {
            editor.putString("isChecked", "true")
            shareLocation()
        } else {
            editor.putString("isChecked", "false")
            stopSharing()

        }
        editor.apply()

    }
}

private fun stopSharing() {
    val stopIntent = Intent(this,LocationServiceforeground::class.java)
    this.stopService(stopIntent)

    isLocationSharing = false
    LocationServiceforeground.stopService(this)
    location.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    beingTrack.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    locationGif.visibility = View.GONE
}

private fun shareLocation() {

    isLocationSharing = true
    LocationServiceforeground.startService(this, "service started")
    location.visibility = View.GONE
    beingTrack.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    locationGif.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (checkLocationPermission()) {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    stopSharing()
    startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
    val editor = sharePreference.edit()
    editor.putBoolean("isActive", false)
    editor.putString("username", "")
    editor.apply()
}
private fun checkLocationPermission(): Boolean {
    var state = false
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && this.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            state = true
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ),
                101
            )
        }
    } else state = true
    return state
}
}
```

Comment: facing the same issue, if you got the solution please do share thank you

Comment: @Birendraasharmaa Still trying.. Dont know why this happens .. once relaunched it cannot be stopped from theat instance

Comment: Your misconception is, that you would be "killing" the app ...which is not the case; try "force stop" once.

Comment: @MartinZeitler When saying "killing" , what I meant was I close the app from the tray too.. Sorry Is said it wrong. But the problem was I am not to stop the previously working service from the button click from any other instance than from the instance where it was started.